# React Hooks- Best place to call a function that depends on state from a "one time" useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm trying to implement google maps using React Hooks without using any kind of third party libraries. I have written code that allows the script to be generated that fetches the google maps using the url as shown below. But I don't know what is the proper way to call this script generating function (`createScriptLoadMap()` in our case), as calling it in `useEffect` that only gets called once seems to give me an error:

> ```
> You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on
> this page. This may cause unexpected errors.
> ```

I want to know why I'm getting this error and how it can be resolved.
Here is a stackblitz link where I've tried my best make a minimal code for my situation:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hsl4dn?file=Hello.js

Edit: I'm also doing a get request from the `useEffect`, so it has to be a "one time" `useEffect`, but I have to call the `createScriptLoadMap()` one time as well and this function depends on the state set by the `useEffect` which is doesn't do immediately!

Is there any way such that the get request happens, sets the `mapCenter` and then the `createScriptLoadMap()` is executed?

Comment: This is because your `createScriptLoadMap()` is calling multiple times, a quick hack is to create a variable with false as initial value and then call `createScriptLoadMap()`, inside the function `createScriptLoadMap()`, set the variable to true. in `useEffect()` check if the variable is false, then call the `createScriptLoadMap()`. Another way is to define map component as class component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `useEffect` hook does execute only one time. You get that message most likely because of the hot reloading and remounting the `Map` component.

In order to avoid that, just use the window property you're setting `window.initMap` to check if the map scripts are loaded:

```jsx
const createScriptLoadMap = () => {
  if (!window.initMap) {
    var index = window.document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    var script = window.document.createElement("script");
    script.src =
      "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDurZQBXjtSzKeieXwtFeGe-jhZu-HEGQU&libraries=drawing&callback=initMap";
    script.async = true;
    script.defer = true;
    index.parentNode.insertBefore(script, index);
    window.initMap = true;
  }
};
```

**EDIT**

As for how to center the map after fetching some data, you should also go with hooks and `useEffect` as you already have a `mapCenter` state object. First use `script.load` to see when script is loaded. Call `initMap` whether the script is loaded or not to get a `google.maps.Map` object and save it using state for later use else if script was already loaded just assign the map object:

```
const createScriptLoadMap = () => {
  if (!window.initMap) {
    var index = window.document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    var script = window.document.createElement("script");
    script.src =
      "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDurZQBXjtSzKeieXwtFeGe-jhZu-HEGQU&libraries=drawing&callback=initMap";
    script.async = true;
    script.defer = true;
    script.onload = () => {
      initMap();
    };
    index.parentNode.insertBefore(script, index);
    window.initMap = true;
  } else {
    initMap();
  }
};
```

Then alter the `initMap` function to initialize or assigng a `google.maps.Map` object to out DOM `#map` element (*that won't create a new map if we're already have assigned the element previously*):

```
const initMap = () => {
  let googleMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: 37.978534, lng: 23.743830 }, //CURRENTLY STATIC
    //center: {mapCenter} //ACTUAL
    zoom: 14
  });

  // Save the map object created for later usage
  setMap(googleMap);

  // axios.get(`${BASE_URL_LOCAL}/outlet/list?page=1&limit=50`).then(res => {
  //   let center = averageGeolocation(res.data.data.outlets);
  //   console.log(props.mapCenter);
  //   setFetchedData(res);
  //   setMapCenter(center) //THIS CENTER IS REQUIRED IN LINE 22
  // });

  // Suppose get an Axios response after 2 seconds
  setTimeout(() => {
    // Center map at NY Brooklyn using state (effect for mapCenter will be triggered)
    setMapCenter({ lat: 40.674282, lng: -73.943060 });
  }, 2000);
};
```

That will create a `google.aps.Map` object and save it using `setMap` state for later usage. Now whenever you want to update the center of the map (*or any other map properties/methods*), just set a `useEffect` hook to `mapCenter` state object and then use the `map` object to alter the map:

```
const [mapCenter, setMapCenter] = useState({});
const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState({});
const [map, setMap] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  createScriptLoadMap();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  if(map) {
    map.setCenter(mapCenter)
  }
}, [mapCenter]);
```

Check my forked and updated [`stackblitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qvrurd?file=Hello.js). You'll see that the map starts from Athens and after 2 seconds delay (*suppose we have an asynchronus Axios call*) it centers the map to NY Brooklyn. (*I created my Google Maps API key for demonstration, I'll delete after your response*).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is indeed a simple solution but that only solves half of my problem, because I need the response from the get request (which I have commented for now) to use it in the initMap(). I have tried to explain it in the stackblitz in line no. 14 and 23. And since that useEffect only happens once, it loads the map with 'createScriptLoadMap()' once, but the 'mapCenter'(line 14) wouldn't have been set because of asynchronocity. Is there any workaround for this? If it was class based, I could've used it in the callback of setState I guess, but I'm stucked with hooks.

Comment: You can create all that logic using hooks. Hooks are so powerful. Just use `script.load` to see when the Google maps script is done loading and then use state to save the map object. Check my updated answer and the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qvrurd?file=Hello.js) that I've made.

Comment: Aah much clear! So, after the axios request happens, we set response to something (say center) which in turn triggers it's useEffect and there, set the map again using the "center's" value appropriately in the map, right? I actually did use this method but I was calling 'createScriptLoadMap()' again in the "center's useEffect" as opposed to just setting the map with appropriate value, and since the script was created again, I was getting the same error. Thank you so much indeed.

Answer (score 0):

**https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ohtdra?file=Hello.js**

Hooks can't help you in this case. Even if you return [clean-up function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect) from useEffect and remove `element` from `head`. Because this script creates a ton of other elements in `head` *(like styles)* and just removing one element will not help.

I need to say that it's not right to do stuff without introducing a React into it, but if you need so, you can. E.g. add something to a script tag and check this next time and skip `createScriptLoadMap`. Like this:

```js
const createScriptLoadMap = () => {
  var gScript = document.querySelector("script[data-setted]");
  var isSetted = gScript && gScript.getAttribute("data-setted");

  if (!isSetted) {
    var index = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src =
      "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDurZQBXjtSzKeieXwtFeGe-jhZu-HEGQU&libraries=drawing&callback=initMap";
    script.async = true;
    script.defer = true;
    script.setAttribute("data-setted", true);
    index.parentNode.insertBefore(script, index);
    window.initMap = initMap;
  } else {
    // I'm not sure about this, can cause a problem
    // but without it stackblitz doesn't render anything
    initMap();
  }
};
```